# javax.imageio.IIOException: Missing Huffman code table entry while Adding text to an jpg image

Tags: java, android, bitmap, jpeg

I am adding text to an image using this code in Android :

```
public Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context gContext, Bitmap image, String gText) {

    Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;

    android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig =
            image.getConfig();
    // set default bitmap config if none
    if(bitmapConfig == null) {
        bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }
    // resource bitmaps are imutable,
    // so we need to convert it to mutable one

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try{
        bitmap = image.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        image.recycle();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        // new antialised Paint
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        // text color - #3D3D3D
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        // text size in pixels
        paint.setTextSize((int) (50 * scale));
        // text shadow
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.BLACK);

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
        int padding = bounds.height()/2;
        int x = bitmap.getWidth() - (bounds.width()+padding);
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() - (bounds.height()+padding));

        canvas.drawText(gText, x, y, paint);
    }catch (Throwable e){
        AppLog.e("DrawingBitmap","error while adding timestamp",e);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Then I create a new File with the transformed bitmap

```
storeImage(newBitmap, newFileName);

 private File storeImage(Bitmap image, String nameFile) {

    File pictureFile = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), nameFile);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        AppLog.e("error creating bitmap", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        AppLog.e("error creating bitmap", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return pictureFile;
}
```

I send the file to my server, I receive an input stream, I create a File, I scale it and I create a new File with the scaled image :

```
ImageWriter.write(metadata, new IIOImage(image, null, metadata), param);
```

I get an IIOException:

```
 javax.imageio.IIOException: Missing Huffman code table entry
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeImage(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeOnThread(JPEGImageWriter.java:1067)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(JPEGImageWriter.java:363)
    at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(JPEGImageWriter.java:162)
```

if I don't call drawTextToBitmap() from android I don't get that error.

If someone can help me ... thx

EDIT : here is the way I use to get metadata from my file

```
    private static IIOMetadata readMetaData(File source)  {
    try {
        ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
        IIOMetadata metadata = null;
        if (readers.hasNext()) {
            ImageReader reader = readers.next();
            reader.setInput(stream);
            metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
        }
        return metadata;
    }catch (Exception e){
        _logger.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Edit 2 :

Using jpegParams.setOptimizeHuffmanTables(true); works but it resets all metadata and I want to keep them like gps location ...

Comment: Is the exception on the server side?

Comment: Try to set value`setOptimizeHuffmanTables(true)` on the jpeg params  which passed to `ImageWriter.write()` method.

Comment: The exception is on server side, if setOptimizeHuffmanTables(true) the result file loses its metadata like gps ..

Comment: if possible post the relevant server code.

Comment: I already post the server code : ImageWriter.write(metadata, new IIOImage(image, null, metadata), param);, if I don't call drawTextToBitmap on android it works, if I call drawTextToBitmap on android then I have an IIOException server side on ImageWriter.write(metadata, new IIOImage(image, null, metadata), param);

Comment: After `storeImage` and before sending to server can you open your file at Android side?

Comment: Yes, and the result is the image + the text drawn on it

Comment: I add the code I use to get the metadata from my file

Comment: did you try not to scale the file on the server but to write it and use it as is?

Comment: try jpegParams.setOptimizeHuffmanTables(true);

Comment: Using jpegParams.setOptimizeHuffmanTables(true); reset all metadata and I want to keep them like gps location ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(quality);
if (param instanceof JPEGImageWriteParam) {
    ((JPEGImageWriteParam) param).setOptimizeHuffmanTables(true);
}
IIOImage image = new IIOImage(reader.read(0), null, reader.getImageMetadata(0));
writer.write(null, image, param);
```

here's my code, which keeps the metadata of image, and get rid of "missing huffman code table" stuff.

Comment: Wow, this saved my application. I'm adding a bounty to award this and show my appreciation. But really it's a workaround to some underlying problem that only occurs with some images. Any idea if there is something we could check beforehand to see if this workaround is needed for an image?